# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.common_libs.structure' has no attribute 'update_struct'

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I'm using TFF 0.18
When using :

```
state = tff.structure.update_struct(state, model=tff.learning.ModelWeights.from_model(keras_model))
```

I find this error, So how can I solve this problem without changing TFF version.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended would be to update your TFF version and not have the problem.

In previous versions, you could have used `tff.utils.update_state` which was updated and moved in [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/commit/70988d7df0886a866ff588c2b15c900f6d43e2b8)